# Fluent nHibernate one-to-many equivalent

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm moving from nhibernate hbm configuration to Fluent nHibernate. I am mapping a section of the hbm file

```
<bag name="ProgramsList" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true" lazy="false">
 <key>
  <column name="ProgramId" />
 </key>
 <one-to-many class="Program" />
</bag>
```

What I have mapped this in fluent api is as follows:

```
HasMany(x=>x.ProgramsList).AsBag().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().Inverse()
.KeyColumns.Add("ProgramId")
```

However, I doubt if I have got this correct, because the last `<one-to-many>` does not figure into it at all. How to do you specify that section of the configuration fluently?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to specify `one-to-many`. This will be folow the `Inverse` and `KeyColumns` on the another side of relation. It know the type if `Program` because it is a generic type in the `ProgramsList` collections.